# cloudinit_config with multi part user_data not getting applied on ec2 windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

all!
I am trying to apply two powershell script one by another after windows ec2 is initialized.
But they arenot applied and no error during terraform execution like hitting 16 user_data constraint is shown. Just inside the ec2 user_data log can see it is not applied and user_data is empty. I will put a chunk of log on the end. So i guess the issue is in my code but not sure what i am doing wrong:

```
#User data template files web/app
data "cloudinit_config" "ec2_user_data" {
  part {
    filename     = "common.ps1"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content = <<-EOF
    <persist>false</persist>
    <powershell>
    ${templatefile("${path.module}/../scripts/common.ps1", {
        computername       = var.computername
        })
      }
    </powershell>
    EOF
  }
  part {
    filename     = "a.ps1"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
      content = <<-EOF
      <persist>false</persist>
      <powershell>
      ${templatefile("${path.module}/../scripts/a.ps1", {
        server_function = var.instance_function_id == "web" ? "web" : "app"
        })
      }
      </powershell>
      EOF
  }
}

#User data template files sql
data "cloudinit_config" "ec2_user_data_sql" {
  part {
    filename     = "common.ps1"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content = <<-EOF
    <persist>false</persist>
    <powershell>
    ${templatefile("${path.module}/../scripts/common.ps1", {
        computername       = var.computername
      })
      }
    </powershell>
    EOF
  }
  part {
    filename     = "sql.ps1"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
      content = <<-EOF
      <persist>false</persist>
      <powershell>
      ${templatefile("${path.module}/../scripts/sql.ps1", {
         computername       = var.computername
      })
      }
      </powershell>
      EOF
  }
} 

resource "aws_instance" "this" {
...
user_data = var.instance_function_id == "sql" ? data.cloudinit_config.ec2_user_data_sql.rendered : data.cloudinit_config.ec2_user_data.rendered
}
```

**EC2Launch**: C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log

```
2022/10/19 12:40:59Z: Begin user data script process.
2022/10/19 12:41:00Z: Unable to parse <persist> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/10/19 12:41:00Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
2022/10/19 12:41:00Z: Unregister the scheduled task to persist user data.
2022/10/19 12:41:03Z: Unable to parse <runAsLocalSystem> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/10/19 12:41:03Z: Unable to parse <script> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/10/19 12:41:03Z: Unable to parse <powershell> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/10/19 12:41:03Z: Unable to parse <powershellArguments> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2022/10/19 12:41:03Z: User data script completed.
```